# Distance from Vector to the Linear Span

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, span

Let $V$ be the space of real polynomials of degree $\leq n$.

a) Check the setting $(f(x),\,g(x))=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)\,dx$ turns $V$ to a Euclidean space.

b) If $n=1$, find the distance from $f(x)=1$ to the linear span $U=\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have edited the question so that the full question is now included.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Due to Pythagoras the square of the distance from $v$ to $\mathrm{span}(u)$ is $\|v\|^2-\langle\frac{u}{\|u\|},v\rangle^2$.